# How do I find order of automorphism group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

What is the order of automorphism of the abelian group $K=c_3 \oplus c_3 \oplus c_3$, where $c_3$ is a cyclic group of order 3.

From the book, I find that $Aut(K)$ is isomorphic to $GL_3(F_3)$. I want to prove this result.
Can anyone suggest me some direction to prove the result.

Comment: Well, the elements of $GL_3(F_3)$ are vector space automorphisms of $F_3^3$, which are in particular group automorphisms of $F_3^3 \cong c_3 \oplus c_3 \oplus c_3$. This gives an embedding $GL_3(F_3) \to \text{Aut}(K)$; all you have to do is show that every group automorphism of $F_3^3$ is linear to get surjectivity!

Answer (score 1):

Any elementary abelian additive $p$-group ($p$ prime)  is a vector space over $GF(p)$: the addition is the group operation in the group and

$$a\circ  x=\underbrace{x+\dots+x}_{a\, \text{ times}}.$$

A map from this group to itself is a group automorphism iff it is a bijective  linear map. So the automorphism group is equal to $GL$.